# How do I make a private phone call?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios10, openurl

This is my sample code I did to hide my number.

```
- (void)openScheme:(NSString *)scheme {
    NSLog(@"%@",scheme);
    scheme = @"telprompt://*67+91-**********";
    UIApplication *application = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
    NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:scheme];
    //URL = [URL URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"*"];
    if ([application respondsToSelector:@selector(openURL:options:completionHandler:)]) {
        [application openURL:URL options:@{}
           completionHandler:^(BOOL success) {
               NSLog(@"call made");
           }];
    } else {
        BOOL success = [application openURL:URL];
        NSLog(@"Open scheme failed");
    }
}
```

It is not working on IOS 10 iPhone 5c. Is there any change I need to do in the settings?

The call popup doesn't appear when I add **67*. It works when I remove it.

Comment: I have not seen an international number starting with *67? Are you sure this is a valid number?

Comment: I am from India it is Indian mobile number.

Comment: *67 is to make private call

Comment: This could be an operator specific functionality in your locality. I would assume this doesn't work, because it does not pass international validation checks, or it has been disabled on purpose by Apple. Not much you can do.

Comment: ok thanks @Legoless

Comment: You can contact Apple Developer Support, if you want a detailed answer, but it is very unlikely that they will change their code anytime soon. You can also file a radar on https://bugreport.apple.com.